# openjdk:8-jre-alpine :- Execute a jar file periodically using docker with cron

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

I want to create a docker file using alpine(as it creates a light weight image) with a cron (to execute a task periodically) , As a newbie I initially tried with ubuntu it worked perfect as i took the help from this link [UbuntuExample with CRON](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/)

Now the problem is it create heavy docker image. I want to convert this same example for alpine but couldn't find the perfect help. Searched a lot of websites but didn't got anything fruitfull.

**MAIN TASK :-**

*My main task is to execute a  java jar file through a docker and execute that jar file periodically*

What I have tried till now is created a simple docker file and a crontab file just to print the message periodically.

Main issue I am facing is install cron on alpine.

**DOCKERFILE (DockerFile)**

```
   FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER docker@ekito.fr

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/hello-cron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

#Install Cron
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install cron


# Run the command on container startup
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**CRONTAB (crontab)**

```
* * * * * root echo "Hello world" >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

This worked perfect for ubuntu but how to achieve it for openjdk:8-jre-alpine

Comment: The image `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine` has crontab and java installed.

Comment: Can you please help me to write a simple dockerfile with cron to just print a simple statement so with the help of it I can write it for executing my jar file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally achieved my task for the  executing java jar using cron. Posting the solution so that it could help other beginners.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
MAINTAINER dperezcabrera

RUN apk update && apk add bash
ADD java-version-cron /temp/java-version-cron
RUN chmod 777 /etc/test/
ADD DockerTesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/test
RUN cat /temp/java-version-cron >> /etc/crontabs/root
RUN rm /temp/java-version-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD crond 2>&1  >/dev/null && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

**java-version-cron**

```
* * * * * java -jar /etc/test/DockerTesting-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar >> /var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# Don't remove the empty line at the end of this file. It is required to run the cron job
```

Place your dockerfile , cron and the jar in the same folder or as according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer. Finally this worked for me

Just one point: It works for me even without last line in cron file.

Answer (score 3):

An example with openjdk:8-jre-alpine image base:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
MAINTAINER dperezcabrera

ADD java-version-cron /temp/java-version-cron

RUN cat /temp/java-version-cron >> /etc/crontabs/root
RUN rm /temp/java-version-cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

CMD crond 2>&1  >/dev/null && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Script `java-version-cron`:

```
*       *       *       *       *       /usr/bin/java -version >>/var/log/cron.log  2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# https://labs.play-with-docker.com/
# add this to dockerfile and execute below two docker commands
# docker build -t cron:test .
# docker run cron:test &

FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

RUN mkdir /app
RUN mkdir /app/bin
RUN mkdir /app/lib
RUN mkdir /app/crontabs

RUN wget https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CROND
RUN mv busybox_CROND /app/bin/crond
RUN wget https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.30.0-i686/busybox_CRONTAB
RUN mv busybox_CRONTAB /app/bin/crontab
RUN chmod +x /app/bin/*

# create HelloWorld.java and compile on the fly, cannot upload files to docker labs
RUN echo 'public class HelloWorld { public static void main(String[]args){ System.out.println("Hello World ..." + new java.util.Date()); } }' > /app/lib/HelloWorld.java
RUN javac /app/lib/HelloWorld.java -d /app/lib

# create entry point script on the fly to avoid windows line ending issues
RUN touch /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo '#!/bin/sh' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo 'echo "* * * * * java -cp /app/lib HelloWorld" | crontab -c /app/crontabs -' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo 'crontab -c /app/crontabs -l' >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN echo 'echo "Executing crond ..."'  >> /entrypoint.sh
# -f foreground flag is important, if this returns, docker exits
RUN echo 'crond -f -l 6 -c /app/crontabs' >> /entrypoint.sh 
RUN echo 'echo "crond exited !!!"'  >> /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```